# How can I solve the problem of replacing the sharp char with an empty char in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a code something like this:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(str_word):

    for char in str_word:
       if char in punctuation_chars:
            new_word = str_word.replace(char,'')
    return new_word

print(strip_punctuation("#inc.red.ible"))
```

This is the output:

```
#incredible
```

For example, in this code above,I couldn't remove that sharp char, or @ char by the replace method. I wonder why it occurs only with these chars.

Answer (score 1):

You read from `str_word` every time, even if you have already made other modifications and saved them into `new_word`.  Make sure you are applying successive modifications to the same string.  For example:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(str_word):
    for char in str_word:
       if char in punctuation_chars:
            str_word = str_word.replace(char,'')
    return str_word

print(strip_punctuation("#inc.red.ible"))
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i think that should solve your problem:

```
def strip_punctuation(str_word):
   for char in str_word:
       if char in punctuation_chars:
           
        str_word = str_word.replace(char,'')
return str_word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the power of regex!

Use the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method from the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']

def strip_punctuation(str_word):
    return re.sub('\\'+'|\\'.join(punctuation_chars), '', str_word)

print(strip_punctuation("#inc.red.ible"))
```

Output:

```
incredible
```